# how can I deploy a react app in aws lambda serverless or S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I created a new react project that reads and writes the files on S3 every minute to generate the data on the page. I want to deploy it on aws lambda or S3 serverless service.
I checked a lot of documents and didn't find the tutorial I wanted. Can I achieve the above requirements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53986227/how-to-deploy-react-app-on-aws-ec2-with-nginx?noredirect=1#comment94811131_53986227

Comment: this post is help https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/deploying-create-react-app-to-s3-or-cloudfront-48dae4ce0af

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done, you need to setup the IAM role/user policy (*serverless-admin*) and the permissions to read/write from S3 bucket. Suggest you set up the aws-cli tool -https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

You will need to setup an aws profile after installing the tool.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

And next Use the serverless framework, https://serverless-stack.com/ to deploy your reactjs applications - This will simplify the process. Follow the tutorial, it will help in understanding the process clearly. I have just done the same, deployed a react js to read/write from a variety of aws services including S3 buckets.

Deploy by running the command on the terminal - `AWS_PROFILE=serverless-admin sls deploy -v  --aws-profile=serverless-admin`

Updates to the code can be deployed using -

```
AWS_PROFILE=serverless-admin sls deploy function -f hello  --aws-profile=serverless-admin
```