# How to deploy React App on AWS EC2 with nginx

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have simple `create-react-app` on AWS EC2, I want to deploy my React app to AWS EC2 instance which I have already created and one of my Django application is running on it using gunicorn and nginx.

Now I want to deploy a react application to that ec2 instance and host the react app with another subdomain here. This react app requires to call APIs hosted to a different EC2 instance.
When I do `npm run build`, it creates a build folder there and when i run `serve -s build` my webpage opens but API is not called.

So, what I want to achieve is:

1. Make API run to the react application in production with axios.
2. Correctly deploy React app to EC2 instance.

Kindly suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: are you getting dist folder in react app? as final output i mean after building

Comment: easy way to deploy app on aws is to use elastic bean stalk with RDS (if database). Elastic bean stalk is like dashboard-panel to deploy app on ec2. direct deploying on ec2 may hard for you

Comment: @harshmanvar I am getting a build folder under my react project

Comment: you mean inside build folder final build files are there ?

Comment: @harshmanvar yes they are there

Comment: go inside build folder...zip the all content inside build folder....any database required ???

Comment: @harshmanvar  No database is required here i use api call to display my data

Comment: open aws after Zipping all content....goto elastic beanstalk

Comment: @harshmanvar I don't want to use it with elastic beanstalk. Can I not do it with EC2

Comment: you can go...but with elastic bean stalk it will be easy to deploy and code will be deploy on EC2 only....elastic beanstalk is like dashboard or easy way to deploy app on ec2...your app will be deployed on ec2 only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185975/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-reema-parakh).

Comment: You don't need EC2 for React app, it's just js and html, so you can just upload it on S3 and deploy django app on EC2 as it will be cheaper. You might need to configure Django to respond to cross-origin requests.